# How to add a variable into my re.compile expression

Tags: python, regex, variables, python-2.7

So I am trying to look through a file for a keyword that is represented by the variable `what2look4`. Whenever I run this program however it keeps returning blank data. The code is as follows:

```
regex2=re.compile(".*(what2look4).*")
```

I believe the problem is that the file is being searched for `what2look4` as a string in itself instead of what that variable represents. Please correct me if I'm wrong, thanks for the help.

Comment: Before it's compiled, a regular expression is a string no different from any other. How would you put a variable's value into any arbitrary string?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do it like so...

```
>>> regex2 = re.compile('.*(%s).*'%what2look4)
```

Or you can use [format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

```
>>> regex2 = re.compile('.*({}).*'.format(what2look4))
```

Comment: This method of string formatting is considering "old". See here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples

Comment: @MartinKonecny: Python's so called *old* printf style formatting using the `%` operator is still supported in Python 3.4 with no sign of being deprecated. There is no issue at all with using tuple unpacking to build a string. In this particular case, for a regex, it is more intuitive that the `.format` method.

Comment: +1 for the two solutions. At first I thought why do we need the `.*` on both sides if we're just looking for a literal? But this makes it into a kind of grep, returning the lines—probably the intention.

Comment: How would you extend this for two variables?

Answer (score 7):

If you're not careful, the answers above can get you into trouble. In most cases, you will want to use `re.escape()` to escape any possible regular expression metacharacters that appear in the string variable you are trying to insert. In addition, both f-strings and the `.format()` method require the use of curly braces `{}`, which are regular expression metacharacters themselves. At the very least, your linter will throw a fit if you try to mix the two.

Although it's much uglier, I would recommend building the regex pattern using string addition. It's the clearest, least error-prone method in this case. The `printf` style should work fine in Python, but I personally don't recommend it because the `%` symbol is the wildcard operator in SQL, and I find it confusing to see in a regex.

Consider the example below where we are looking for a file name that could be in any folder and that we expect to end with a date.

```py
# Note that "\d" is a regular expression metacharacter!
file_name_var = "\data"

# Option 1: string addition
re.compile(r'^.*' + re.escape(file_name_var) + r'_\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}.csv$')

# Option 2: printf style
re.compile(r'^.*%s_\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}.csv$' % re.escape(file_name_var))
```

Comment: Is it possible to pass a variable in place of the numbers inside d{}?

Answer (score 5):

Use a [String format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

```
search = "whattolookfor"
regex2=re.compile(".*({}).*".format(search))
```

The `{}` inside the string will be replaced with `whattolookfor`

Comment: How do you cope with regex with `{}` as part of regex?