# Regular Expression passing variable

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have a list and 3 strings. I want to search list variables in string.

```
str1 = 'lol cry'
str2 = 'lol'
str3 = 'cry'

l1 = ['lol', 'cry']

for wo in l1 :
    if re.match(r"^"+wo+"$|\s+wo+$", str1, re.M|re.I):
        print "yes"
```

My regex here is wrong. I want to add "wo" as a variable in `|` condition. But my code is taking it as a string. If I pass str1, str2, str3 to my regex, it has to return yes.

Comment: I'm not geting what you want to do. Can you please rewrite your question together with some sample input and output?

Comment: Of course it is; you included `wo` in the quotes, unlike the first occurrence where it is a separate variable. `r"^" + wo + "$|\s+" + wo + "$"`

Comment: @chepner That still doesn't match `str1`, though.

Comment: @StefanPochmann I'm just pointing out that `wo` isn't being used as a variable.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24637917/how-to-add-a-variable-into-my-re-compile-expression/24638062#24638062

Comment: consider this- str1 = 'lol cry'; str2 = 'abscsad'; str3 = 'lol cry rofl'; 
l1 = ['lol','cry', 'dance'] .. Now if I pass str1 to regex.... it must return true .. cause string is starting with lol which is one of the items in list... next it has space and next word is another item from list. str2 obsly returns false. str3 also should return false. it starts with the item of the list has space has item of the list again but it has something that is not in the list. so it will return false.

Answer (score -1):

I found one of the good ways to do it.

```html
for wo in l1:
 for eo in l1:
  if re.match(r'^{0}+($|\s+{1}+$)'.format(wo, eo), str1,re.M|re.I):
   print "True"
```